# Aggregate Monthly Values

Tags: python, datetime

I have a python list containing multiple list:

```
 A = [['1/1/1999', '3.0'], 
      ['1/2/1999', '4.5'],
      ['1/3/1999', '6.8'],
      ......
      ......

      ['12/31/1999', '8.7']]
```

What I need is to combine all the values corresponding to each month, preferably in the form of a dictionary containing months as keys and their values as values.

Example:

```
   >>> A['1/99']
   >>> ['3.0', '4.5', '6.8'.....]
```

Or in the form of a list of list, so that:

Example:

```
  >>> A[0]
  >>> ['3.0', '4.5', '6.8'.....]
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: "What I need is to combine all the values corresponding to each month, preferably in the form of a dictionary containing months as keys and their values as values."

Comment: right, I got that part.  It's a statement, though, not a question.  What happened when you tried to implement "combine all the values corresponding to each month, preferably in the form of a dictionary containing months as keys and their values as values."?

Comment: I read this as Aggregate Monty Python list, I am disappointed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    from collections import defaultdict
    from datetime import date

    month_aggregate = defaultdict (list)
    for [d,v] in A:
        month, day, year = map(int, d.split('/'))
        date = date (year, month, 1)
        month_aggregate [date].append (v)
```

I iterate over each date and value, I pull out the year and month and create a date with those values. I then append the value to a list associated with that year and month.

Alternatively, if you want to use a string as a key then you can

```
    from collections import defaultdict

    month_aggregate = defaultdict (list)
    for [d,v] in A:
        month, day, year = d.split('/')
        month_aggregate [month + "/" + year[2:]].append (v)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This method, however gives a dictionary containing all the dates and their corresponding values. I was looking for month based aggregation..like all the values for january are accessed by month_aggregate['1/11']. I am sorry for my english, it is bad .. let me know if you need it rephrased.

Comment: Either of the two approaches above will aggregate by month. The first creates date objects corresponding to a month (each day gets mapped to the 1st of the month). The second uses keys of the form month/year.

It depends what you want to do - if you want to do further date calculations on the keys, then having them as date objects could be useful, but if you want to display the keys in that particular form then just keep them as strings.

Comment: Thank you Owen, great approach :-)

Comment: one little thing..considering the second approach, what would be the implementation using python's datetime module?

Answer (score 3):

Pandas is perfect for this, if you don't mind another dependency:

For example:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np

# Generate some data
dates = pandas.date_range('1/1/1999', '12/31/1999')
values = (np.random.random(dates.size) - 0.5).cumsum()

df = pandas.DataFrame(values, index=dates)

for month, values in df.groupby(lambda x: x.month):
    print month
    print values
```

The really neat thing, though, is aggregation of the grouped DataFrame. For example, if we wanted to see the min, max, and mean of the values grouped by month:

```
print df.groupby(lambda x: x.month).agg([min, max, np.mean])
```

This yields:

```
         min       max      mean
1  -0.812627  1.247057  0.328464
2  -0.305878  1.205256  0.472126
3   1.079633  3.862133  2.264204
4   3.237590  5.334907  4.025686
5   3.451399  4.832100  4.303439
6   3.256602  5.294330  4.258759
7   3.761436  5.536992  4.571218
8   3.945722  6.849587  5.513229
9   6.630313  8.420436  7.462198
10  4.414918  7.169939  5.759489
11  5.134333  6.723987  6.139118
12  4.352905  5.854000  5.039873
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution without includes

```
def getKeyValue(lst):
    a = lst[0].split('/')
    return '%s/%s' % (a[0], a[2][2:]), lst[1]

def createDict(lst):
    d = {}
    for e in lst:
        k, v = getKeyValue(e)
        if not k in d:    d[k] = [v]
        else:             d[k].append(v)
    return d

A = [['1/1/1999', '3.0'],
     ['1/2/1999', '4.5'],
     ['1/3/1999', '6.8'],
     ['12/31/1999', '8.7']]

print createDict(A)
>>>{'1/99': ['3.0', '4.5', '6.8'], '12/99': ['8.7']}
```